# Unresolved reference when modifying a Maven dependency to Maven local

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

In my Flutter app I use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/cunning_document_scanner) dependency. On Android it depends on [this](https://github.com/WebsiteBeaver/android-document-scanner) dependency to show a document scanner. I've forked the second dependency and did some modifications to make it work for my use case.

Now I want to configure the first dependency to use the local version of the second one instead of the one that is on Maven.

So far I have figured out that I need to add a second repository to the `build.gradle` file called `mavenLocal`. I've put `mavenLocal` above `mavenCentral` as some guides instructed. Initially this seems to work as now Android Studio gets autocomplete for my modified code.

However, when I try to run the example application provided with the first plugin, I get an "Unresolved reference" error.

Currently my modified `build.gradle` file looks like this:

```
// ...

rootProject.allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

// ...

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "com.websitebeaver:documentscanner:1.3.5"
}
```

Is there anything more I need to add to the `build.gradle` file to make builds work?

Thanks